# Delete /tmp subvolume on btrfs partition scheme and make systemd-tmpfiles work with default tmpfs /tmp directory

Tags: systemd, btrfs, tmpfs, tmp

I've made the mistake of mounting the `/tmp` directory as a btrfs subvolume. The problem is that `systemd-tmpfiles` won't clean it. How can I delete the `/tmp` subvolume and fix this? I'm new to filesystems, specially btrfs, and don't know much about how tmpfs and systemd(except for creating simple services) work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the subvolume and removing its entry in `/etc/fstab` fixed.